# Restricting access to certain accounts

Tags: case, permissions, account

We have partners who need to log into Salesforce and view cases they have with accounts they own. The issue here is that they each own only three or four accounts, and can't, under any circumstances, be able to see other accounts or their cases. I've ready some about accomplishing this through Sharing Settings & Roles, but it seemed quite cumbersome the ideas proposed there. Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish the task of allowing an internal Salesforce user to be limited to just a few accounts and those accounts cases?

Comment: "internal Salesforce user" or "partners"? What is the license type?

Comment: Essentially, they'd be very similar to normal agents working cases, except they could only see an access THEIR accounst and their cases. So the license type is just "Salesforce."

Comment: So if you set the OWD to private and those users as the record owner of their own accounts  / cases, does this solve the issue? Or you have other use cases not shared here?

Comment: @KaonZ OWD to private would probably work but it's not in the cards right now. I didn't know about that solution before posing this question, though